# Defined number of rows and columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Can I make a workbook in Excel and dictate the number of rows and columns? For example 20 rows and 5 columns? I am working on a spread sheet that will always have the same number of rows and columns and I would like to disable the scrolling to infinity option.

Comment: select the entire row or column, right click, hide.

Comment: select all the unused rows or columns, right click and hide them

Answer (score 0):

Wether [Excel Worksheet Format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) has a fixed size for the worksheets    (1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns) , you will need to do one of this tricks:

> - Limit number of rows and columns with disabling scrolling in Excel
> - Limit number of rows and columns with hiding rows and columns

There you have a [link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2649-excel-limit-number-of-rows-columns.html) where they clearly explain both of methods with images and all steps required.

Answer (score 0):

The code bellow hides the extra rows and columns, and limits cell selection / movement

(just update MAX_COL and MAX_ROW constants in Module1)

---

Code in **ThisWorkbook** module:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MinimizeAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        MinimizeSheet ws
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MinimizeAllSheets
End Sub

'If ScrollArea is not set
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    RestrictMovement Target
End Sub
```

---

Code in **Module1** (generic module):

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Const MAX_COL = 5   'Update default limits (all sheets)
Private Const MAX_ROW = 20

Public Sub MinimizeSheet(Optional ByRef ws As Worksheet, _
                         Optional ByVal maxCol As Long = MAX_COL, _
                         Optional ByVal maxRow As Long = MAX_ROW)

    If maxCol > 0 And maxRow > 0 Then
        Dim actWs As Worksheet
        If ws Is Nothing Then
            Set ws = ActiveSheet
        Else
            If ws.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
                Set actWs = ActiveSheet
                ws.Activate
            End If
        End If
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        With ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, maxCol + 1), ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count))
            .EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End With
        ws.Rows(maxRow + 1 & ":" & Rows.Count).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        'ScrollArea also limits the selection
        ws.ScrollArea = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1), ws.Cells(maxRow, maxCol)).Address
        If Not actWs Is Nothing Then actWs.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

.

```
Public Sub RestrictMovement(ByVal Target As Range)  'If ScrollArea is not set
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            If .Column > MAX_COL Then .Parent.Cells(.Row, MAX_COL).Activate
            If .Row > MAX_ROW Then .Parent.Cells(MAX_ROW, .Column).Activate
        Else
            If (.Column - 1) + .Columns.Count > MAX_COL Then
                Set Target = .Resize(.Rows.Count, MAX_COL)
            End If
            If (.Row - 1) + .Rows.Count > MAX_ROW Then
                Set Target = .Resize(MAX_ROW, .Columns.Count)
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```